# How to get the attribute id by attribute code in magento 2

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2.2, attribute-set

I have the attribute code, But how do I check whether the attribute is exist in the attribute set or not. Please provide me a solution how to get the attribute id from attribute code in magento 2

Comment: Try this one-
**`https://webkul.com/blog/get-attribute-id-attribute-code-magento2/`** You can also see how we can get customer and company name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get Attribute Id By Attribute Code In Magento2.

Just you have to follow some steps.

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    private readonly \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute $eavAttribute
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
}
 
//Call the getIdByCode method of Attribute in any method.

//Your $this->_eavAttribute->getIdByCode('entity_type', 'attribute_code');

$attributeId = $this->_eavAttribute->getIdByCode(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
    'company_name'
);
```

Also you can check more details [here](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-attribute-id-name-value-from-attribute-code/).

Comment: Can you tell me , What i have to replace in the place of customer and company_name

Comment: Fatal Error: 'Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Magento\\Eav\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Entity\\Attribute::getIdByCode(),

Comment: It shows error like above

Comment: @Sri use your ->getIdByCode('entity_type', 'attribute_code');

Comment: thanks , I have tried like this  $attributeId =  $this->_eavAttribute->getIdByCode(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,'color');

Comment: @Jaisa Thanks for the comment, works for me ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a product attribute repository class to do this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $productAttributeRepository,
) {
    $this->productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
}

public function example()
{

    $attribute = $this->productAttributeRepository->get('size');
    $sizeId = $attribute->getAttributeId();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$entityAttribute = $objectManager->get('Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute');
$attributeId = $entityAttribute->getIdByCode('ENTITY TYPE', 'ATTRIBUTE CODE');
```

> for example, get the `product attribute` ID with the attribute code `brand`:

```
$attributeId = $entityAttribute->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'brand');
```